# how to generate unique sequence number -sql

Tags: sql

Im able to generate sequence of numbers while inserting a new row in existing table. For example I have,

```
Row1 1
Row2 2
Row3 3
```

Now if I **delete** the `second Row` it becomes,

```
Row1 1 
Row3 3
```

But what i want to get is,

```
Row1 1
Row3 2
```

Is there any way to obtain this **without manually** updating each and every row in DB?

Comment: databases  typically has custom way to do this.  auto increment/sequence etc.  What is your database?

Comment: So everything that *references* row3 also has to be updated? And the assigned IDs aren't stable? Sounds like something you should generate when *querying* the table rather than something to be stored.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: Damien is right.  Sequences are generally related to primary keys and should not be changed, as they might alter the meaning of any foreign dependencies.  You should put more information as to why you want to get that and specify what your idea of *manually* is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the row with `num = 2`

You can do something like:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `num` = `num` - 1 WHERE `num` > 2
```

Similarly, if you insert a row somewhere you can increment `num` to make space for the new record.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `num` = `num` + 1 WHERE `num` >= 2
```

(2 now becomes available)

If you move a record, you can do something like:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `num` = `num` - 1 WHERE `num` > 2 AND `num` < 10
```

Moving 2 to 10

Append a new record can be:

```
INSERT INTO `table` SET `num` = MAX(`num`) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is "yes".  You can update every row *except* the first one.

```
update t
    set id = id-1
    where id > 1
```

Okay, I understand your intention, so let me be less literal.  There is no reason to change an id in the table itself.  You can do the calculation when you query it:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
from t
```

You can even put this into a view, to make it more widely and consistently available.

Comment: Sequence numbers are not the same as ids. ids can part of a foreign key relation. A sequence number merely indicates an order. You can't use the same number.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen . . . The point being that the sequence numbers can be generated when needed for querying and don't need to be updated in the table.  If that doesn't meet the OPs needs, then s/he will no doubt communicate that.